# Plugin for Right-to-Left and Bottom-to-Top scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was given a project for a webpage that requires the following behavior:

Intro Content displays on screen with a full-page background image.

As the user scrolls down, the next content section scrolls up to display on a full-page with its own background image.

As the user keeps scrolling down, the next content sections scrolls from right (to left) to display its own full-page content with a background image.

And every remaining slide continues taht behavior (scrolling from right off-screen to left view).

I'm not sure I have the time to build a custom solution, so I was hoping there's a pre-existing library that basically allows me to set HTML attributes to determine the direction of scrolling/sliding for each slide.

Something like this:

```
<li class="slide active" scroll-direction="bottom-to-top">Slide 1</li>
<li class="slide" scroll-direction="bottom-to-top">Slide 2</li>
<li class="slide" scroll-direction="right-to-left">Slide 3</li>
<li class="slide" scroll-direction="right-to-left">Slide 4</li>
<li class="slide" scroll-direction="right-to-left">Slide 5</li>
```

Comment: Have you checkout this plugin : https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Answer (score 0):

Try [ScrollMagic](https://scrollmagic.io/) for complex scrolling animations. See this [demo](http://atintell.com/) which seems similar to your needs.